# How to change permissoin of $Extend directory? Python? C++?

Tags: c++, python-2.7, ntfs, access-denied, cacls

I want to hide a text file by moving it to `$Extend` directory ([What is this directory?](http://ntfs.com/ntfs-system-files.htm)). So I run `cmd` as *Administrator*  and run the below code :

```
C:\Windows\system32>copy I:\ToHide.txt I:\$Extend
Access is denied.
        0 file(s) copied.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

As you see, I couldn't and I received *Access Denied* error. So I tried to takeown the destination directory (`$Extend`) and change its `ACLs` as below :

```
C:\Windows\system32>takeown /f I:\$Extend

SUCCESS: The file (or folder): "I:\$Extend" now owned by user "Abraham-VAIO\Abra
ham".

C:\Windows\system32>cacls I:\$Extend /G Abraham:F
Are you sure (Y/N)?Y
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

**Q1: Why cacls couldn't see this directory, while takeown could!?**

After that, I use the below python code :

```
import win32api
import win32con
import win32security

FILENAME = "I:\\$Extend"
open (FILENAME, "w").close ()

print "I am", win32api.GetUserNameEx (win32con.NameSamCompatible)

sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity (FILENAME, win32security.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
owner_sid = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorOwner ()
name, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountSid (None, owner_sid)

print "File owned by %s\\%s" % (domain, name)
```

And I receive *Access Denied* again :

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abraham\Desktop\teste.py", line 6, in <module>
    open (FILENAME, "w").close ()
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'I:\\$Extend'
>>>
```

**Q2: Is this python code equal to `takeown` or it is an alternative for `cacls`?**

**Q3: Why I receive access denied,while I run idle (and after that python in command-line) as Administrator?**

Last questions :

**Q4: Why I can't open this directory using Windows Explorer, While I can open it using WinRAR? Does Windows restrict some APIs for Explorer but they are available for other softwares?**
[image]

[image]

By the way, Is there any way to I achieve my goal using Python or C++ or ...? (Hiding something in $Extend directory)

Comment: IMHO, it is bad practice trying to hide something in a *system* directory unless you exactly know how the system uses it. I would advice you to look at the excellent truecrypt utility and it you really want to hide something at the truecrypt hidden volumes. And that way you will be sure not to break anything.

Comment: Does'nt OS with the new files in the system directories, just like other file and directories? I mean, doesn't OS store the contents of $Extend just like other files?

Comment: I do not know, but the only question is do **you** know it ... I only know what is MFT and know it is **very** special.

Comment: I want to do it manually not by any third party software! Maybe I break something! but in my experience it is not important! I just want to copy the files in $Extend

Comment: Why do you want to hide your file under $extend specifically? From which user/process do you want to hide it / what is the context of your question?  In general, you can hide data in the MFT in all kinds of locations, e.g. you might have some spare unused bits in MFT records which you can use.

Comment: @tal I want to hide my file in this location because this is the last location people think about it!!! So it is hard to find! How I can use those unused bits in MFT? Am I need any special software?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can access the MFT directly by opening \.\PhysicalDriveX - which is the underlying physical disk (X is the number of the disk you want to open) - and then parse the disk directly, i.e. find the partition offset from the Master Boot Record, then parse the first NTFS sector and from there find the location of the MFT.

There is a great open source sample of how to parse the MFT in the ntfsfastfind project, see here:
http://home.comcast.net/~lang.dennis/console/ntfsfastfind/ntfsfastfind.html

I also recommend that you read about NTFS internals here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134(v=ws.10).aspx
http://ntfs.com/ntfs-mft.htm

Comment: Thank you dear tal. I'll test then as as soon as possible and the I'll accept your answer.